# How to populate a new column in R using already existing data?

Tags: r

This is related to a common question on here, and I think it has a simple answer, but I am kind of stumped.

I am hoping to populate a new column in R based on two other columns. Normally I would write the conditions as well as outcomes based on those condition and then point it at a new column. In this case however, I'm trying to fill in values I already have, they're just in a different row. Here is an example:

```
Example Dataset:

df <- data.frame(Candidate = c("Allison" , "Bob" , "Ralph" , "Doug" , "Ben"), State = c("NY" , "NJ" , "NY" , "FL" , "FL"), District = c(1,3,1,2,2), Party = c(1,2,1,1,2), Trait1 = c(5,4,3,2,3), Trait2 = c(5,3,2,5,4))
> print(df)
  Candidate State District Party Trait1 Trait2
1   Allison    NY        1     1      5      5
2       Bob    NJ        3     2      4      3
3     Ralph    NY        1     1      3      2
4      Doug    FL        2     1      2      5
5       Ben    FL        2     2      3      4
```

I would like to go through every candidate populate  a new column containing Trait1 for the candidate sharing the same district and state.

```
    Candidate State District Party Trait1 Trait2 Opponent.Trait1 
1   Allison    NY        1     1      5      5        3
2       Bob    NJ        3     2      4      3        NA
3     Ralph    NY        1     1      3      2        5
4      Doug    FL        2     1      2      5        3
5       Ben    FL        2     2      3      4        2
```

I am not sure how to use the df$Trait1 as the output for this operation. This is a simple question I think, but I can't  figure out how I would  do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a naïve solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)    

df %>% 
  group_by(State, District) %>%
  mutate(Opponent.Trait1 = ifelse(Trait1 == min(Trait1), ifelse(Trait1 == max(Trait1), NA, max(Trait1)), min(Trait1)))

# # Groups:   State, District [3]
#   Candidate State District Party Trait1 Trait2 Opponent.Trait1
#   <fct>     <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1 Allison   NY           1     1      5      5               3
# 2 Bob       NJ           3     2      4      3              NA
# 3 Ralph     NY           1     1      3      2               5
# 4 Doug      FL           2     1      2      5               3
# 5 Ben       FL           2     2      3      4               2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only ever have 1 opponent maximum, you could reverse the trait column within each group to get the intended result.

```
ave(df$Trait1, df[c("State","District")], FUN=function(x) if(length(x)==1) NA else rev(x) ) 
#[1]  3 NA  5  3  2
```

If you don't mind a warning being thrown, you could shorten this to:

```
ave(df$Trait1, df[c("State","District")], FUN=function(x) x[2:1] )
```

Anyway, in `dplyr`, the same logic holds:

```
df %>%
  group_by(State,District) %>%
  mutate(optrait = if(n()==1) NA else rev(Trait1) )
```

And in `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
df[, optrait := if(.N==1) NA_real_ else rev(Trait1), by=.(State,District)]
```

An update join in `data.table` may be more robust to duplicate rows for Candidates, but my solution is a bit ugly:

```
df[, optrait := 
   df[
     df, on=c("State","District"),
     if(.N==1) NA_real_ else Trait1[Candidate!=i.Candidate],
     by=.EACHI
   ]$V1
]
```